# Using layout specific javascript in comfy leads to InvalidCrossOriginRequest

Tags: javascript, security, xss, ruby-on-rails-4.1, comfortable-mexican-sofa

I'm using [Comfy](https://github.com/comfy/comfortable-mexican-sofa) for building custom layouts within the web application. My problem now is, that when I try to embed the code for dynamically loading the javascript as follows:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag comfy_cms_render_js_path(@cms_site.id, @cms_layout.identifier) %>
```

This code can be found in my `application.html.erb` file.

When I now load the page with a comfy-defined layout I get this error:

```
ActionController::InvalidCrossOriginRequest (Security warning: an embedded <script> tag on another site requested protected JavaScript. If you know what you're doing, go ahead and disable forgery protection on this action to permit cross-origin JavaScript embedding.)
```

One possibility to resolve this issue is to remove the attribute `protect_from_forgery` in the `application_controller.rb` file. But this is not a good solution.

The same problem occurs when I embed the links to the javascript within the layout in the admin panel.

I hope you can help me.

Comment: Why don't you try constructing html tag manually. Don't do it through `stylesheet_link_tag` helper.

Comment: Nope, that does not work either! And it is the javascript not the stylesheet tag what causes problems.

Comment: Hmm. Right. I think CMS need to skip forgery protection on the asset serving action. I'll create a ticket.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Issue is fixed in current master: https://github.com/comfy/comfortable-mexican-sofa/issues/458